# MySQL trigger update parent table when child table is updated

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I use two tables in a MySQL database. Table "parent" (`parent_id, name, modified,` ...) and table "children" (`child_id, name, parent_id,`...). The relation is `parent.parent_id` <-> `children.parent_id`.

I need a trigger in MySQL that sets "modified" in "parent"-table to "1" whenever a related record in "children" was updated.

Thanks for your help!

Below is the code that I tried

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER set_parent_modified_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON children

BEGIN 
  UPDATE parent SET parent.modified = 1 WHERE parent.parent_id = children.parent_id;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

It resulted in a mysql error -> "unknown field children.parent_id"

Comment: You may want to declare that as a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger and use `new.parent_id` to access the value set by the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you @sticky bit !!! It already solved my problem :-)

Comment: @Uwe Kempf,  please post the code in response to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER set_parent_modified_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON children
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE parent SET parent.modified = 1 WHERE parent.parent_id = new.parent_id;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;

Problem Solved
Thanks @sticky bit
```